# Babel error with css

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, css-modules

I write ReactJS application with css-modules.

My component:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { renderRoutes } from 'react-router-config';

import styles from './Layout.css';

const Layout = ({ route }) => (
  <div className={styles.layout}>
    {renderRoutes(route.routes)}
  </div>
);

Layout.propTypes = {
  route: PropTypes.object,
};

export default Layout;
```

I have a SSR. In development environment i run `babel-node ./src/server.jsx`. And I get this error:

[image]

my **.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": "7.1"
        }
      }
    ],
    "react-app"
  ]
}
```

How ignore css files?

Comment: What are you using to build your project? Probably need some kind of loader for css.

Comment: My project build with webpack, but ssr don’t use weback